# Implementing a Keyword Search

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

A more detailed explanation follows, but the core of my question is:  **what are best practices for implementing a general keyword search in SOQL/Apex?**

---

In an app that I'm building, we're using a data structure where we have a custom junction object (Junction__c) reflecting a many-to-many relationship between Accounts and another custom object (Custom__c):

[image: Junction__c joins Accounts to Custom__c]

In the app, we're displaying Junction__c records that match a variety of criteria on the related Account and Custom__c records.  There are actually a bunch of criteria, but this gets the idea across:

```
SELECT Id, Other__c, Fields__c
       Account__r.Field1__c, Account__r.Field2__c,
       Custom__r.Field3__c, Custom__r.Field4__c,
FROM Junction__c
WHERE Account__r.Field1__c = :inputVar1 AND Custom__r.Field3 = :inputVar2
```

We just got a new requirement from our product owner, that we need to support a general keyword search on about 10 fields from the Account and Custom__c records.  That basically means adding another `WHERE` clause like this, which seems really inefficient, particularly because I'll be searching against **long text fields**:

```
AND (Account__r.Field1 LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR Account__r.Field2 LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR Custom__r.Field3 LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR Custom__r.Field4 LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR [etc.])
```

After poking around a bit, I got the idea of doing the keyword search in SOSL and using those results in my SOQL:

```
List<List<sObject>> keywordResults = [FIND 'keyword' IN ALL FIELDS
                                      RETURNING Account (Id)
                                                Custom__c (Id)];
List<Account> keywordAccounts = keywordResults.get(0);
List<Custom__c> keywordCustom = keywordResults.get(1);

// later...

String keywordWhereClause = 'AND (Account__r IN :keywordAccounts
                                  OR Custom__r IN :keywordCustom)';
```

This approach seems OK in theory, but I don't know how to gauge performance implications of these multiple queries, and I'm concerned about the documented restriction that [SOSL is limited to the top 200 result](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limit.htm)s, since our data set will be bigger than that.

---

So back to my original question.  **With this set of requirements and constraints, how can I effectively perform a keyword search?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've scratched my head on a similar use case for long. You can workaround the limitation of SOSL returning top 200 results by following the wokaround mentioned on this thread - [Apex SOSL Paging Implementations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/894/apex-sosl-paging-implementations)

As for the SOSL limitation itself, it's been there as an idea for some time now.

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqzpAAC