# How to find a value in all column of an object?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

How to find `field_name/api_name` name for any `object` that contains a value?

I'm working on a object that has dozens of fields but I'm after finding out particular value belongs to which field name.

for an example:

I have a value `ABC123` in `MyCustomObject`

one possible way I can do is something like this:

```
SELECT field_name FROM MyCustomObject WHERE field_name = 'ABC123' || field_name2 = 'ABC123' etc... but this is very tedious.
```

Comment: do you want to add all fields and there value in where condition?

Comment: that's one way to do it but i have dozens of fields and what i'm looking is more like a generic so i can use for any other sobject.

Comment: you can get the all sobject fields.. but for value you need to query

Comment: yes for value i need to query but what about the fields do i need to write all dozens of fields as i have shown in my question. show what you thinking so i will get better understanding.

Comment: In which data you are interested? Are you interested in matching records or the API names of fields where ABC123 would be found?

Comment: @AbuHamzah check Tushar ans you need SOSL that will look for  values in all Fields..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making dynamic soql why don't you use SOSL.

try this query

```
List<Sobject> Results = [FIND 'ABC123' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING customobject(Id, Name)];
```

or if you have dynamic value then

```
string searchQuery = 'FIND \'' +searchtext+'*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING customobject(Id, Name)';
Search.query(searchQuery)
```

and you don't need to write all fields.

You can also find a good example [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15149/how-to-search-a-text-in-all-fields-in-all-objects-and-return-all-values). It also handle 2000 records limit in SOSL.

Comment: ohh yes.. I was thinking. He want to get all the fields values that why gave that ans.. Good catch @Tushar.. Yes this the best ans for question,  +1 for you...